# Is it possible to control who sees TFS 2017 Server Settings?

Tags: tfs-security

Is it possible to prevent underprivileged users from accessing Settings even if they are in Read-Only mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't the security setting to achieve that.

All users who have access to the project have access to view the permissions and settings. As there is no conceivable security risk from this, as they can't change anything. It is available to all.

You can set the permissions based on your requirements to restrict them to certain accesses. See [permissions-access](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions-access) for details.

If you want to have that feature you can submit a user voice on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Comment: Hi Andy, than you very much.